# Is SAP PI messaging service JMS compliant?

Tags: jms, integration, sap-pi, sap-xi

I am trying to find out if the built-in SAP PI messaging service JMS compliant or not?

Could not find it in the public documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The PI JMS Adapter (Version 7.4 AEX) is compatible with JMS 1.02b and 1.1, as described in SAP Help Portal (help.sap.com) > Advanced Adapter Engine > Configuring the JMS Adapter ([link 7.40](http://help.sap.de/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/cd/d85a9d6fab7d4dbb7ae421f710626c/content.htm) and [link 7.50](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5cf7d2de571a45cc81f91261668b7361/7.5.17/en-US/cdd85a9d6fab7d4dbb7ae421f710626c.html)):

> The JMS adapter (Java Message Service) enables you to connect messaging systems to the Integration Engine.
>
> The adapter supports the JMS specifications 1.02b and 1.1.

Cheers
Jens